# How do I resolve a type error in this code?

Tags: python, pyscripter

```
def turn_clockwise(point):
    all_point = ["N", "E", "S", "W"]
    for loop in range[4]:
        if all_point[loop] == point:
            if loop == 3:
                return "N"
            else:
                return all_point[loop + 1]
```

**Message from the Python interpreter on PyScripter:**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "D:\Documents\Pyscripter
> practice\Chp.6 Exercises - Fruitful functions.py", line 25, in
>  test_suite()
>  File "D:\Documents\Pyscripter
> practice\Chp.6 Exercises - Fruitful functions.py", line 21, in
> test_suite test(turn_clockwise("N") == "E")
>  File
> "D:\Documents\Pyscripter practice\Chp.6 Exercises - Fruitful
> functions.py", line 5, in turn_clockwise for iteration in
> range[4]:
>  TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `range` is a class, and you can't use indexing `[...]` with classes. You want `(...)` there.

Comment: Alternative way: Create a dictionary with `dict(zip(all_point, all_point[1:] + all_point[:1]))`. With this approach you need only one line of code after the definition of `all_point` and that is: `return dict(zip(all_point, all_point[1:] + all_point[:1])).get(point, None)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `()` brackets instead of `[]` because `range` is a Class which we need to call.

```py
def turn_clockwise(point):
    all_point = ["N", "E", "S", "W"]
    for loop in range(4):
        if all_point[loop] == point:
            if loop == 3:
                return "N"
            else:
                return all_point[loop + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for loop in range(4) instead of range[4]
```

As it iterates from 0 to range-1